# How do I change the mouse cursor icon for the Sway Wayland compositor?

Tags: cursor, sway

Under i3 I could change the mouse cursor icon by editing `~/.Xresources`, is it possible to change the mouse cursor icon for Sway?

Answer (score 1):

From the man page of Sway :

```
       The following environment variables have an effect on sway:

   SWAY_CURSOR_THEME
       Specifies the name of the cursor theme to use.
```

I didn't try but that might be useful.

Comment: With this method, the default cursor theme still shows on window titles and on the status bar.